How to use the fancy mathcal characters with notomath
I am using the notomath package beacuse I really like the Noto font, except from the mathcal characters:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{notomath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
    \mathcal{A B C D E F W X Y Z}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}


I was looking into the package documentation and found a character table that includes a set of fancier fonts:

How can I set these fonts as my mathcal fonts?
Also, the characters I get from the mathcal command aren't even in this table.

Welcome to TeX SE. Could you post a compilable code that shows what you have?

@AlainRemillard Thank you. Just edited my post to include a minimal reproducible example.

They are available as mathscr.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{notomath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
    \mathcal{A B C D E F W X Y Z}
    \mathscr{A B C D E F W X Y Z}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}


Oh, nice, thank you. They look a bit smaller in comparison, is there a way to scale them?

@AlfredoReis there must be a way but really in that case it would be simpler to ignore the ones here and simply load a different set stix as egreg suggested or the rsfs or rsfsx fonts. this notomath package isn't a simple font it's a collection of setup and virtual fonts and mappings to pull together what the author considered a consistent set. If you like it that's convenient but if the provided options are not enough, picking it apart is probably harder than starting from scratch with a known default state.

I guess you want to borrow the font from STIX Two
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{notomath}
\usepackage[cal=stixtwofancy,calscaled=0.95]{mathalpha}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
A\mathcal{A B C D E F W X Y Z a b c d e f g}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}



why not the script from the notomath package? :-)

@DavidCarlisle Because this way is much more efficient. The script characters used by notomath are actually from newtxmath and not in a standard position, so each token in the argument has to be processed quite extensively.

yes sure but the question asked about the characters shown in the package doc

Ok, this could work. Thanks!
